# Wordpress auto post update

Tags: wordpress, post, process

Is possible to update a word press post with some kind of automatic process?

We have several post process attached to the save_post action and we want to make a auto post update process every n time.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by "update a wordpress post" do you mean periodically modifying the "post modified date" ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer.


Now we have a wordpress with a method inside an action "save_post". When we update with the IDE of wordpress manually the product, a process call an API to update the images of this product...


We need to invoke this update method in automatic way every n time for each product post...


Do you know if it can be possible?